# How can I deserialize Datetime json with correct timezone c#

Tags: json.net

My application consumes the APIs, one of the API returns the Datetime value with unix time format

```
ex: user.DateOfBirth = "/Date(476197200000+1100)/"
```

The deserialize process is working well (`deserialize<User>` object) but when I display the datetime to GUI.

the UI displays this date as 2/Feb/1985 
My expected is: 3/Feb/1985

My local environment displays correctly, it's 3/Feb/1985, but on UAT environment, it display less than 1 day (2/Feb/1985)

I'm using Newtonsoft.Json v10.x.x

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how you are deserializing but you might want to look into how to parse using specific time zone.

You can try this.

```
microsoftDateFormatSettings = 
new { DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.MicrosoftDateFormat,
      DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Local};

var items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<lstObject>>.
(jsonString, microsoftDateFormatSettings);
```

Comment: Hello Rushikesh Vyas 

Thanks for your reply, yes, I have been serializing as your above suggestion, I also add ateTimeZoneHandling.Local but not success 

My Json is: "DateOfBirth":"\/Date(784731600000+1100)\/" 
My Customer has: 
        [Description("The contacts date of birth.")]
        [DataMember(IsRequired = false)]
        public DateTime? DateOfBirth { get; set; } 

Could you help me in this case? 

Thank you

Comment: Can you show the snippet of your code?that’d be a great help.

Comment: It's exactly the same like you, the difference is using <T> object instead of List<object>, and microsoftDateFormatSettings change to your suggestion above 

Thank you

Comment: So do you see the correct value when you deserialize and UI control is showing wrong date? Or when you deserialize json you are getting incorrect information